# Overwrite CSV config element data read into memory when test has started

Tags: jmeter-5.0

I am overwriting a csv data file element 
that is referenced by a thread group later in my test plan because by default Jmeter loads it at start up into memory. I then use a SetUp thread group to overwrite the data because the data is updated in an external data source some times. But when using this approach I am occasionally getting nulls for data items overwritten.

How can I update a data file in a thread group that is loaded at startup without suffering from nulls?

Comment: You should provide some of your code, it is possible the error is somewhere there, but we can't help you without seeing it.

Comment: It do not think it is not the code because the data file it overwrites is exactly the same format, just varying number of rows. If the original had 64k rows in memory, the one it overwrites may have 106k rows. I think if is more groovy script that would read in the existing file, then overwrite It that is required. But I cannot find suitable code.

Comment: The file write code I use is: 
 //Build the 'File' name and location
File writeToFile = new File(dataFileRoot+fileName);

//Write the formatted result set to file - false = overwrite file, if append use true
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(writeToFile, result.toString(),"UTF-8",false);

Comment: I need more details, so I can help you, it is still not clear to me. Where do you get nulls? In a file or somewhere in the code? Do you write into the same file in parallel threads?

Comment: Hi DD, it was an issue with the application, compounded by the custom error handling which was misconfigured resulting in seeing nulls in the errors, when it was the SOAP request with the issue. Apologies. I think this should be closed.